# Upgrading PHP 7.04 to 7.06 Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: php7, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Xenail Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

I've PHP 7.04 , How can I update that too 7.06 ? Cant seem to work with apt-get upgrade ?

Comment: I've also tried and that didnt work either.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: So I can get a upgraded version

Comment: What do you think is missing? You do understand that while Ubuntu (Canonical) will NOT change the major version (i.e. 7.04), Cononical WILL backport updates for the life of the supported version AFTER very substantial testing, etc? In other words, you don't necessarily need to be on the "latest" version to have what you require. [Last update](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1/changelog) was May 19, 2016. So, again, question is what do you think you are getting in standard 7.06 that is not in the Canonical updated Xenial 7.04 version?

Comment: And, if you were going to do this, you might consider the 7.0.7-4ubuntu2  yakkety-release on 2016-06-10, which at least has _some_ Canonical support, rather than looking to an _unknown_ ppa.

Comment: Reason I ned to upgrade so I can run Magento 2.1.0 and requirements are either 5.x which I dont want to use as later on the releases they will surely require 7.x0 php e.t.c..

Comment: @Colt could you please let me know how I can add that release sudo add-apt-repository ppa:??

Comment: you have to use apt-get "pinning"

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu [PinningHowto wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto), including good info on possible problems and what to be careful of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install php 7.08

```
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Adding the following sources

```
deb ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main 
deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
```

It installed PHP 7.08 with no errors.